# How do I define a variable that identifies the background color of the window (python, tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I asked a question related to this previously and with the help of a user comment, I can now get a little more specific in my question:

Basically I am trying to create a "game show buzzer" type system that simply changes the background color of my window depending on who "buzzes" in first (by pressing either the right or left arrow). So if left is pressed the background turns green, if right is pressed, the background turns pink. However, being VERY new to python and programming in general, I'm struggling to figure out how to tell the program to ignore the second "buzzer". In other words if the left arrow is pressed first, I want it to ignore the right arrow until I "reset it". I currently have that as me pressing the enter key to turn the background black again.

Right now I'm trying to set up some code that says "if the background is this color go ahead and change it. If the background is a different color, ignore the key press". The problem I'm having is knowing how to tell python to check the color of the window background. Any thoughts??  Thanks so much for all of the help!

Here is my current code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class FullScreenApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        #create full screen window
        self.master=master
        pad=3
        self._geom='200x200+0+0'
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            master.winfo_screenwidth()-pad, master.winfo_screenheight()-pad))
        master.bind('<Escape>',self.toggle_geom)
        master.bind('<Left>', self.LeftArrowKey)
        master.bind('<Right>', self.RightArrowKey)
        master.bind('<Enter>', self.EnterKey)
    def toggle_geom(self,event):
        #toggle geometry of window when Escape is pressed
        geom=self.master.winfo_geometry()
        print(geom,self._geom)
        self.master.geometry(self._geom)
        self._geom=geom
    # "Buzzer keys" and "Reset" back to black
    def LeftArrowKey(self,event):
        if bgcolor()==bgcolor("black"):
            self.master.configure(background="green")
    def RightArrowKey(self, event):
        self.master.configure(background="deep pink")
    def EnterKey(self, event):
        self.master.configure(background="black")
    def bgcolor(self):


root=Tk()
root.configure(background="black")
root.title("Who buzzed in first?")
app=FullScreenApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: use variable to keep information who pressed first. or variable `already_pressed == False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a flag, and check for that flag when processing the keystrokes.

You can use a dedicated variable, or you can use the default background as the fla, which it appears you're already doing in `LeftArrowKey`. Just do the same for both keys: if the color is currently black, set it to the player's color. If it's not black, then the event was too late and you do nothing (or add to a score, or display a message, ...)

You can use the `cget` method to get the current color.

```
def LeftArrowKey(self,event):
    if self.master.cget("background") == "black"):
        self.master.configure(background="green")
    else
        print("You are too slow!")
```

To use a dedicated flag, first is to make sure you initialize it at the start of the game:

```
self.winner = None
```

Then, you can check it in your functions:

```
def LeftArrowKey(self,event):
    if self.winner is None:
        self.master.configure(background="green")
        self.winner = "green"
    else
        print("You are too slow!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Colorchange = True

def LeftArrowKey(self,event):
    if bgcolor()==bgcolor("black") and Colorchange = True:
        self.master.configure(background="green")
        Colorchange = False
```

when resetting just set Colorchange back to True

Comment: `bgcolor()` and `bgcolor("black")` were just made-up functions by the OP. I think he was asking how to get the background color.

Comment: @BryanOakley oh I assumed he declared the functions, but didn't add them right here.